# Partitioning ordered integers into lists of consecutive integers

Tags: list-manipulation, partitions

I have a list of ordered integers, e.g. `{1,2,3,6,7,9,10}` and I would like to partition the list into sublists of sequential numbers, e.g.  `{{1,2,3},{6,7},{9,10}}`. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 12):

```
Split[{1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 9, 10}, #2 - #1 == 1 &]
```

> {{1, 2, 3}, {6, 7}, {9, 10}}

Comment: How come you're using `Chop` here? It works fine without it.

Answer (score 9):

Also

```
FindClusters[{1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 9, 10}]
```

Comment: FindClusters is O(sqrt n), but split is O(n log n)

Comment: @M.R. Really, thx for the information! I didn't know it.

Answer (score 3):

**Using `Sequence*` functionality:**

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 9, 10};

SequenceCases[list, {a__} /; 
   ContainsOnly[Differences[{a}], {1}] :> {a}]

SequenceCases[list, {a__} /; Times @@ Differences[{a}] == 1 :> {a}]
```

and since overlaps are not used here:

```
SequenceReplace[list, {a__} /; 
   ContainsOnly[Differences[{a}], {1}] :> {a}]
```

---

```
patt = {Alternatives @@ Complement[Range @@ MinMax@list, list]};
SequenceSplit[Range @@ MinMax@list, patt]
```

---

*Result:*

```
{{1, 2, 3}, {6, 7}, {9, 10}}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 9, 10};

take =
 {First[#], Splice @ Differences[#], All} &[
  First /@ SequencePosition[list, {a_, b_} /; b - a > 1]]
```

{3, 2, All}

```
TakeList[list, take]
```

{{1, 2, 3}, {6, 7}, {9, 10}}

Comment: The output of `take` is `{3, Splice@*{2}, All}` for `v12.2`, although the `Splice` command is available in this version. Can you please take a look?

Comment: Thank you, it should have been `@` instead of `@*`

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 9, 10};
```

---

Another way defining `AccumulateConsecutive` and using `Fold`:

```
AccumulateConsecutive[acc_, x_] := 
If[acc === {} || Last[Last[acc]] + 1 != x, Append[acc, {x}], 
ReplacePart[acc, -1 -> Append[Last[acc], x]]]
```

Testing `AccumulateConsecutive`:

```
Fold[AccumulateConsecutive, {}, list]

(*{{1, 2, 3}, {6, 7}, {9, 10}}*)
```